# Execute function alternately

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I alternately perform 2 different functions

Example: Function 1 executed After 20 seconds function 2 executed and then everything starts again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. (It'll probably involve a flag variable or similar piece of state information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function function1() {
  // Do what you have to do...
  console.log("Function 1 called");
  setTimeout(function2, 20000);
}

function function2() {
  // Do what you have to do...
  console.log("Function 2 called");
  setTimeout(function1, 20000);
}

function1();
```